# Java Static initializers referring to subclasses: avoid class loading deadlock

Tags: java, static, classloader, deadlock

I have a class `ItemType` with final static fields that refer to instances of a subclass:

```
public static final ItemType DURATION = new BuiltInAtomicItemType(x);

static class BuiltInAtomicItemType extends ItemType {

    public BuiltInAtomicItemType(X x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
```

And this gives rise to the possibility of a class loading deadlock if one thread loads the superclass first while the other class loads the subclass first.

Now the problem is that this is a public API and I can't easily change it. I want to remove the possibility of a class loading deadlock, but I don't want to force change on applications that refer to `ItemType.DURATION` or the other 40-odd similar fields.

Is there a way to avoid the potential deadlock while retaining the public API?

Comment: How likely is it that the two classes (one being a member of the other) will be loaded by different class loaders?

Comment: We get very occasional reports of such deadlocks - perhaps one a year, from a large user community. It's a small problem statistically, but I don't like having to tell users that "these things just happen sometimes".

Comment: i guess you should foward this to Oracle.... sounds more like a compilation issue... i mean, there is nothing wrong with the code. It is all legal.

Comment: Deadlocks in static initializers are a well known issue, see for example https://www.farside.org.uk/201510/deadlocks_in_java_class_initialisation. My question is about how to change my code to avoid the known problem.

Answer (score 4):

Status report: no-one seems to know a solution to this problem. Designing a class structure in a complex application to avoid all possibility of deadlocks during class loading and initialization appears to be very difficult. Modifying an existing application to eliminate such possibilities without making incompatible changes to public APIs appears in the general case to be impossible.